# Find number of non-singular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> If $w$ is complex cube root of unity $w \ne 1$ then find number of non-singular matrices of the form
>   $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & a & b\\ 
>  w&1  &c \\ 
> w^2 &w  & 1
> \end{bmatrix}$$ such that $a,b,c$ takes values from the set $S=\left\{w,w^2\right\}$

My Try:

we have $$\det(A)=acw^2-(a+c)w+1$$.

$\det(A)=0$ only if $ac=1$ and $a+c=-1$ since $1+w+w^2=0$.

So $a=w $ ad $c=w^2$ OR $a=w^2$ and $c=w$.

But since $\det(A)$ is independent of $b$ The final possible triplets $(a,b,c)$ are

$1.$ $(w,w^2,w^2)$

$2.$ $(w^2,w,w)$

$3.$ $(w,w,w^2)$

$4.$ $(w^2,w^2,w)$

So total number of singular matrices is $4$.

But total number of matrices $A$ is $8$.

Hence total number of non-singular matrices is $8-4=4$.

But my book answer is $2$. May I know where is the mistake?

Comment: Hint: $acw^2 -(a+c)w+1$ can be factored as $(aw-1)(cw-1)$.

Comment: Your mistake lies in the argument that "$\det(A)=0$ **only if** $ac=1$ and $a+c=-1$ since $1+w+w^2=0$". This "only if" statement is false, although the converse is true.

Answer (score 3):

The matrix $A$ is singular iff
$$0=\frac{\det(A)}{w^2}=\frac{1}{w^2}-(a+c)\frac{1}{w}+ac=
\left(\frac{1}{w}-a\right)\left(\frac{1}{w}-c\right)$$
that is iff $a=1/w=w^2$ and $c\in S$ or $c=1/w=w^2$ and $a\in S$. So there are two more cases: $(w^2,w^2,w^2)$ and $(w^2,w,w^2)$.

Hence the total number of non-singular matrices is $2^3-(4+2)=2$.